# microsoft access 2010 Not In List event

Tags: ms-access-2010

I am VERY new to access and am working on a database.  I have a form (frmHomeowner) with a bound multi-column combo box for zip codes (cboZip). The combo box is based on a query from tblZipCity [zipid (PK), zipcode, city, state] and the city and state text boxes get filled automatically once a zip code is selected. 
I am trying to add the option of adding a new zipcode to the list with the Not In List event of the cboZip by opening the frmCitiesZip to add the new record :

```vb
Private Sub cboZip_NotInList(NewData As String, Response As Integer)
Dim Result
Dim Msg As String
Dim CR As String

CR = Chr$(13)

' Exit this subroutine if the combo box was cleared.
If NewData = "" Then Exit Sub

' Ask the user if he or she wishes to add the new zip code.
Msg = "'" & NewData & "' is not in the list." & CR & CR
Msg = Msg & "Do you want to add it?"

If MsgBox(Msg, vbQuestion + vbYesNo) = vbYes Then

' If the user chose Yes, start the CityZip form in data entry
   ' mode as a dialog form, passing the new zip code in
   ' NewData to the OpenForm method's OpenArgs argument. The
   ' OpenArgs argument is used in the homeowner form's Form_Load event
   ' procedure.

   DoCmd.OpenForm "frmCitiesZip", , , , acAdd, acDialog, NewData
 End If

' Look for the zip code the user created in the zip code form.
Result = DLookup("[zipcode]", "frmCitiesZip", _
         "[zipcode]='" & NewData & "'")
If IsNull(Result) Then
' If the zip code was not created, set the Response argument
   ' to suppress an error message and undo changes.

Private Sub Form_Load()
If Not IsNull(Me.OpenArgs) Then
  ' If form's OpenArgs property has a value, assign the contents
  ' of OpenArgs to the zipcode field. OpenArgs will contain
  ' a zip code if this form is opened using the OpenForm
  ' method with an OpenArgs argument, as done in the homeowner
  ' form's cboZip_NotInList event procedure.
  Me![zipcode] = Me.OpenArgs
  End If
 End Sub
```

But I seem to run into a problem around this line:

Result = DLookup("[zipcode]", "frmCitiesZip", _
             "[zipcode]='" & NewData & "'")
    If IsNull(Result) Then

When I type a zip code not currently on the list I get the prompt asking me if I want to add to the list but after I add it to the frmCitiesZip and close the form I get an error message:
Run-time error ‘3078’ saying that access cant find the input table or qry ‘frmCitiesZip’.

The frmCitiesZip is based on qryCitiesZip. Not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `DLookup` needs a query or a table as domain https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DLookup-Function-8896cb03-e31f-45d1-86db-bed10dca5937?omkt=en-US&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US . So use `qryCitiesZip` instead of  `frmCitiesZip

Comment: I tried using qryCitiesZip instead of frmCitiesZip but I still get the same error message. Any other suggestion?

Comment: `qryCitiesZip` exists? Check for typos!

Comment: i used the table and it worked. thanks!